# Append specific line in text file as item 1 of value list in dictionary and subsequent lines as 1 string to item 2 of the same list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file to import to dictionary but I have an issue trying to get the program to identify the correct line no as item 1 and items 2 in a list in dictionary

The format of text file is like this (there is no empty line between each lines and only at the end of each record, there is a line break):

```
ProductA

2020-08-03 16:26:21

This painting was done by XNB.

The artist seeks to portray the tragedies caused by event XYZ.

The painting weighs 2kg.

####blank line#####

ProductB

2020-08-03 16:26:21

This painting is done by ONN.

It was stolen during world war 2.

Decades later, it was discovered in the black market of country XYZ.

It was bought for 2 million dollars by ABC.


###blank line###
```

Desired outcome in dictionary:

```
{ 'ProductA' : ['2020-08-03 16:26:21', 'This painting was done by XNB.The artist seeks to portray  the tragedies caused by event XYZ. The painting weighs 2kg.'], 'ProductB':['2020-08-03 16:26:21','This painting is done by ONN.This painting is done by ONN.Decades later, it was discovered in the black market of country XYZ.It was bought for 2 million dollars by ABC.']}
```

where item_2 is a single string that is combined from line 3 onwards till the end of the information where it meets a blank line.

Problem: I don't know how to code the logic in such as way that the program will be able to properly assign it to where I want it to.

```
header = ""
header = True

for line in records:

        data = line.splitlines()

        if line!= '\n': # check for line break which indicate new record

            if Header: #

               #code which  will assign 1st line of each record as key to dictionary

            else:
               # This is where I need help. 
               # Code which  will assign 2nd line as item_1 and then assign 3rd lines onwards till the end of record as item_2 in a single string.
               # items_2 may have different number of lines being combined into 1 string for each record.
               # I try to form a rough idea how the logic might be in code below but I feel that something is missing and I got a bit confused.
            
                for line in list: # result in TypeError,  'type' object is not iterable.
                        dict[line[1]] = dict[header].append(line[1].strip("\n")) 
                        # Since the outer if has already done its job of identifying 1st line of record. The line of code seeks to assign the next line (line 2 in text file) which I think would be interpreted by the program as line[1] to item 2.

                        dict[line[2:]] = dict[header].append(line[2:].strip("\n"))
                         # Assign 3rd line of text file onwards as a single string which is item_2 in the list of value for dictionary.

          else: 

             #code which reset boolean for header
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    data = fp.read().split('\n\n')
res = {}
for x in data:
    k, v = x.strip().split('\n', 1)
    v = v.split('\n')
    res[k] = [v[0], ' '.join(v[1:])]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
{'ProductA': ['2020-08-03 16:26:21', 'This painting was done by XNB. The artist seeks to portray the tragedies caused by event XYZ. The painting weighs 2kg.'], 'ProductB': ['2020-08-03 16:26:21', 'This painting is done by ONN. It was stolen during world war 2. Decades later, it was discovered in the black market of country XYZ. It was bought for 2 million dollars by ABC.']}
```

Comment: Hi Deadshot, I have tried to test your code but it's output becomes like this: {'Key_1': ['line 3', 'line 4', 'line2', 'line5']}
I have forgotten to mention that line 2 of the text file is the time and date which is '2020-08-15 15:20:10' not too sure if it will cause interference to the sorting of lines. Are there any ways out?

Comment: Hi Deadshot, thank you very much!  *Bow to you* Senpai!